# Excel Aggregation- Combine Data Over Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, aggregate

I was working on a project and the data downloads into Excel in the wrong format:

| Product ID | Product Name | Area | Product Suite | Placement | Total | Labor | Hardware |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Sample Product 1 | Fort Worth | Test Suite 1 | Unit | $5,000 | $0 | $5,000 |
| ABC | Sample Product 1 | Fort Worth | Test Suite 1 | Unit | $2,500 | $2,500 | $0 |
| BCD | Sample Product 2 | Waco | Test Suite 2 | IT | $1,200 | $0 | $1,200 |
| BCD | Sample Product 2 | Waco | Test Suite 2 | IT | $1,000 | $1,000 | $0 |

This is how I want my table to look:

| Product ID | Product Name | Area | Product Suite | Placement | Total | Labor | Hardware |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Sample Product 1 | Fort Worth | Test Suite 1 | Unit | $7,500 | $2,500 | $5,000 |
| BCD | Sample Product 2 | Waco | Test Suite 2 | IT | $2,200 | $1,000 | $1,200 |

I have Excel 2013 and do not have access to Power Query. I was wondering what I could do to format my data such that the costs are all broken down in one line, rather then a new entry for each portion of the cost. All the other columns that are not cost will always be the same for a given Product ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a pivot table.

---

To get to below format place the fields you want to group by in rows and the fields you want to sum by in values.

Then, go to the design tab and turn off Subtotals, Grand totals, and change the Report Layout to Tabular

[image]